# SQL query to get values at a point in time

Tags: date, t-sql

I am trying to write a query that retrieves information from an HR database.  There are two tables I am interested in.

Table 1 - tbuser_salary.  This table has columns:

- id - unique ID
- id_1 - user ID
- start_date - the effective date of the change
- amount - the salary

Table 2 - tbuser_working_patterns.  This has columns:

- id - unique ID
- id_1 - user ID
- effective_date - the effective date of the change
- working_pattern - e.g. MMTTWWTTFF

The objective is to show what the amount and working_pattern are when either of them change.  I have also been asked to exclude the most recent data for each user.

I think I need to start off with a UNION ALL of the tbuser_salary start_date values and tbuser_working_patterns effective_date values and then re-join to those tables to say what was the amount and working_pattern value at this point in time, however I am really struggling to get my head around it:

```
--Get the dates where salary changed
select id_1, start_date, amount, null
from tbuser_salary 
where id not in 
(
select max(id) 
from tbuser_salary
group by id_1
)

UNION ALL 

--Get the dates someone's working pattern changed
select id_1, effective_date, null, working_pattern
from tbuser_working_patterns
where id not in
(
select max(id)
from tbuser_working_patterns
group by id_1
)
```

Any points would be very gratefully received.  Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue with your query ? Does it gives the required result?

Comment: The query only gives me all of the dates that either the "amount" value or the "working_pattern" value changed.  I need to expand it so that it shows me the working_pattern at the point the salary changed and the salary at the point the working_pattern changed.  Thanks.

Comment: Since you want to keep track of changes in both of the tables what I would do is to create two audit tables e.g tbuser_salary_audit/tbuser_working_patterns_audit and two seperate triggers in the original tables executing on updates. That way when you update a row on the original table you can insert the previous value on the audit table.

Comment: If you provide some sample data for both tables (preferably as a script to generate the data) and then the expected results it should be easier for readers to solve.

Comment: Like Alan said, We may need sample data. I'm thinking this might be simply an OUTER APPLY resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to be able to produce a data set which contains all the dates, with the values for salary and working pattern for each user.

Using some demo DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @UserSalaries TABLE (SurrogateID INT IDENTITY, UserID INT, StartDate DATE, Amount DECIMAL(10,3));
DECLARE @UserWorkingPatterns TABLE (SurrogateID INT IDENTITY, UserID INT, EffectiveDate DATE, WorkingPattern VARCHAR(14));

INSERT INTO @UserSalaries (UserID, StartDate, Amount) VALUES
(1, '2023-01-01', 100.00), (1, '2023-03-01', 200.00), (1, '2023-06-01', 300.00), 
(2, '2023-02-01', 100.00), (2, '2023-09-01', 200.00),  
(3, '2023-03-01', 100.00), (3, '2023-06-01', 150.00), (3, '2023-09-01', 200.00); 

INSERT INTO @UserWorkingPatterns (UserID, EffectiveDate, WorkingPattern) VALUES
(1, '2023-01-01', 'MTWRF'), (1, '2023-09-01', 'MWF'), 
(2, '2023-01-01', 'MTWRF'), (2, '2023-09-01', 'WRFSN'), 
(3, '2023-01-01', 'MTWRF'), (3, '2023-09-01', 'NMTWR');
```

Ideally, you would have a calendar table, which already contains all the dates. You can remove the first two CTEs (and the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION)`) here as they just produce a pseudo data set as a stand in.

```
;WITH Calendar AS (
SELECT MIN(StartDate) AS Date, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS mDate
  FROM @UserSalaries
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date), mDate
  FROM Calendar
 WHERE Date < mDate
), UserSalaryRanges AS (
SELECT SurrogateID, UserID, Amount, StartDate, COALESCE(DATEADD(DAY,-1,LEAD(StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY StartDate)),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS EndDate
  FROM @UserSalaries u
), UserWorkingPattenRanges AS (
SELECT SurrogateID, UserID, WorkingPattern, EffectiveDate AS StartDate, COALESCE(DATEADD(DAY,-1,LEAD(EffectiveDate) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY EffectiveDate)),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS EndDate
  FROM @UserWorkingPatterns u
), UserSalaryByDate AS (
SELECT usr.SurrogateID, usr.UserID, usr.Amount, c.Date, CASE WHEN c.Date = usr.StartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsChange
  FROM UserSalaryRanges usr
    INNER JOIN Calendar c
      ON c.Date BETWEEN usr.StartDate AND usr.EndDate
), UserWorkingPatternByDate AS (
SELECT usr.SurrogateID, usr.UserID, usr.WorkingPattern, c.Date, CASE WHEN c.Date = usr.StartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsChange
  FROM UserWorkingPattenRanges usr
    INNER JOIN Calendar c
      ON c.Date BETWEEN usr.StartDate AND usr.EndDate
)

SELECT usbd.Date, usbd.UserID, usbd.Amount, uwpbd.WorkingPattern, 
       usbd.IsChange AS SalaryChange,
       uwpbd.IsChange AS WorkingPatternChange
  FROM UserSalaryByDate usbd
    INNER JOIN UserWorkingPatternByDate uwpbd
      ON usbd.Date = uwpbd.Date
      AND usbd.UserID = uwpbd.UserID
 ORDER BY UserID, Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Here we're producing some CTEs to create ranges for both the salary and working pattern data, with start and end dates. From there, we can join the calendar table and produce a row for each date, marking the start of the range as a change. Finally, we can join the two data sets together using date and user id.

| Date | UserID | Amount | WorkingPattern | SalaryChange | WorkingPatternChange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-02-28 | 1 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-03-01 | 1 | 200.000 | MTWRF | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-03-02 | 1 | 200.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-05-31 | 1 | 200.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 1 | 300.000 | MTWRF | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 1 | 300.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-08-31 | 1 | 300.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-09-01 | 1 | 300.000 | MWF | 0 | 1 |
| 2023-09-02 | 1 | 300.000 | MWF | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-10-04 | 1 | 300.000 | MWF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-10-05 | 1 | 300.000 | MWF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-02-01 | 2 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-02-02 | 2 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-08-31 | 2 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-09-01 | 2 | 200.000 | WRFSN | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-09-02 | 2 | 200.000 | WRFSN | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-10-04 | 2 | 200.000 | WRFSN | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-10-05 | 2 | 200.000 | WRFSN | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-03-01 | 3 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-03-02 | 3 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-05-31 | 3 | 100.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-06-01 | 3 | 150.000 | MTWRF | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-06-02 | 3 | 150.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-08-31 | 3 | 150.000 | MTWRF | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-09-01 | 3 | 200.000 | NMTWR | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-09-02 | 3 | 200.000 | NMTWR | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2023-10-04 | 3 | 200.000 | NMTWR | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-10-05 | 3 | 200.000 | NMTWR | 0 | 0 |